# NextFocusRight doesn't focus on the right, but down

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm work on an app with multiple `edittext`.
When an `edittext` take the whole width, the `nextfocusdown` is working properly.
But when there is two `edittext` at the same height (each edittext takes half of the width), I want to give the focus from the left one to the right one.
But when i write `nextFocusRight="id/EDIT_RIGHT"` in my xml, the focus doesn't goes to the right `edittext` but goes to `edittext` under the left one.

[image]

```
    <!-- EDIT LEFT-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EDIT_LEFT"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_left_hint"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/EDIT_RIGHT"
        tools:ignore="Autofill"/>

    <!-- EDIT RIGHT-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EDIT_RIGHT"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_right_hint"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/EDIT_DOWN"
        tools:ignore="Autofill"/>
```

Comment: android:nextFocusRight="@+id/EDIT_RIGHT"
add + between @ and id

Comment: @Mohitpatel I did'nt worked, the problem is the same :c

Comment: if you just want to move the cursor or the focus to next edit text. then use imeoptions property and set to actionNext

Comment: @Mohitpatel do you have any example of how it works ?

Comment: Please don't add [solved] devices to titles - we don't use them here. Additionally, the code formatting edits on the question look OK - please leave them be. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use like this -

```
<!-- EDIT LEFT-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EDIT_LEFT"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_left_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/EDIT_RIGHT"
        tools:ignore="Autofill"/>

    <!-- EDIT RIGHT-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EDIT_RIGHT"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_rgiht_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/EDIT_DOWN"
        tools:ignore="Autofill"/>
```

You should use   android:nextFocusRight="@+id/EDIT_RIGHT" instead of   android:nextFocusRight="@id/EDIT_RIGHT" because you are using this edittext before creating it and use imeOptions.

Comment: Answer updated with Mohit's suggestion.  Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using `android:nextFocusDown="@id/EDIT_DOWN"`.

Use `android:nextFocusForward="@+id/EDIT_DOWN"`.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edt_height"
    android:background="@drawable/edt_back_shape"
    android:hint="Enter email"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/size_5dp"
    android:text="@={viewmodel.email,default=``}"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_10dp"
    android:id="@+id/emailEdt"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/websiteEdt"
    android:textSize="@dimen/form_edt_text_sizes"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/stNoEdt"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailTitle"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_light"
/>
```